# Installing AngularJS is showing warning message

Tags: angularjs, npm-install

I am trying to install AngularJS, When I do restore packages of `package.json` file, it shows a warning message on **output** windows.

**Warning message**

```
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] lodash has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=lodash&version=3.10.1 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.3.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] ws has the following vulnerability: 1 high. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=ws&version=1.1.2 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] debug has the following vulnerability: 1 low. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=debug&version=2.2.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] minimatch has the following vulnerability: 1 high. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=minimatch&version=0.3.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] parsejson has the following vulnerability: 1 high. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=parsejson&version=0.0.3 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm WARN notice [SECURITY] https-proxy-agent has the following vulnerability: 1 high. Go here for more details: https://nodesecurity.io/advisories?search=https-proxy-agent&version=1.0.0 - Run `npm i npm@latest -g` to upgrade your npm version, and then `npm audit` to get more info.
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
added 614 packages in 106.81s
```

This is my node and npm version

> node -v     v8.11.0
>
> npm -v      5.6.0

Is there anything wrong with my installation?

I am using windows 10 64 bit

**Update**

After I run this below command

```
C:\Users\liam>npm i -g npm
C:\Users\liam\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\liam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
C:\Users\liam\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm -> C:\Users\liam\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
+ npm@6.4.1
added 387 packages in 29.578s

C:\Users\liam>
```

Then When I **Restored packages** of `Package.json`

It shows

```
====Executing command 'npm install'====


npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
audited 4242 packages in 5.854s
found 18 vulnerabilities (9 low, 9 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

====npm command completed with exit code 0====
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `npm` version is out-of-date.

Please update your global `npm` via following commands.

```
$ npm i -g npm
```

If you use **linux/ubuntu** or **OS X** then attach prefix `sudo`.

```
$ sudo npm i -g npm
```

Comment: should I run that command on the root directory of my project?

Comment: @Liamneesan it doesn't matter. **`-g`** means global

Comment: @Liamneesan it's okay anywhere in the terminal. `-g` will indicate that npm runs globally.

Comment: @lealceldeiro still it shows the error. Can you see my update?

Comment: @Liamneesan checked your updated logs. I think it doesn't matter anyhow. Since `package-lock.json` has been introduced, we'll frequently meet some vulnerabilities which ask `npm audit`. They can be ignored.

Comment: @Liamneesan As you can see from warnings, `fsevents@1.2.4` is not supported on windows!